# Bootable drive for MacBook Air without CD/DVD drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootable-disk

I'm considering getting a MacBook Air. Since it doesn't have a CD/DVD drive, how can you deal with issues that would otherwise call for a bootable install disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MacBook Air has a hidden Recovery partition that you can use to fix your system and reinstall OS X. Apple has a page on it [here](http://www.apple.com/ca/osx/recovery/). To access it, just hold Command(⌘)-R while your computer is booting up.

If you really need a install USB, Apple has a tool to make one. You can download it [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433).

Answer (score 0):

Simply with other bootable devices like USB thumb drives or USB/ThunderBolt/FireWire External drives !

Or if you absolutely need a CD/DVD Drive you can use a [USB SuperDrive](http://store.apple.com/fr/product/MD564ZM/A/superdrive-usb-apple).